# Consulta SQL en dos tablas

Tags: sql

Tengo dos tablas

clientes

```
nif | poblacion
----------------
123 | londres
234 | madrid
456 | paris
```

y la otra es vuelos

```
pasajero | asiento
------------------
123      | 012
234      | 05v
456      | 6v4
```

Estoy tratando de obtener solo los vuelos de Madrid y Londres y no logro obtenerlos... ¿que estoy haciendo mal?

```
Select * FROM vuelos JOIN clientes ON clientes.nif = vuelos.pasajero WHERE poblacion = 'madrid' 'londres'
```

Gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utiliza el operador `in` o aplica dos condiciones con `or` a los dos valores 'madrid', 'londres', tomando en cuenta que el campo `nif` y `pasajero` sean del mismo tipo.

Ejemplo usando el operador `in`:

```
Select * FROM vuelos JOIN clientes ON clientes.nif = vuelos.pasajero 
WHERE poblacion in('madrid', 'londres')
```

Ejemplo usando condiciones con `or`:

```
Select * 
  FROM vuelos 
       JOIN clientes ON clientes.nif = vuelos.pasajero 
 WHERE vuelos.poblacion = 'madrid'
    or vuelos.poblacion = 'londres'
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no podia solucionarlo.